# tesseract (v3.03) output as PDF

Tags: linux, ocr, tesseract

Why is this error returned?

```
root@amd-3700-2gb ~/ocr_test # tesseract -l dan pdf.png out pdf
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica
Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/osd.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'osd'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Warning: Auto orientation and script detection requested, but osd language failed to load
```

## Language list

```
root@amd-3700-2gb ~/ocr_test # tesseract --list-langs
List of available languages (3):
eng
dan
dan-frak
```

## Output as txt

This works fine and output text to `out.txt`

```
tesseract -l dan pdf.png out
```

## Output PDF

This creates `out.pdf` but also retuns the error mentioned and the searchable text in the PDF doesn't make sense

```
tesseract -l dan pdf.png out pdf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is clear: it needs `osd.traineddata` file. You can install or download Orientation & Script Detection Data for Tesseract from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata.

Comment: The repository has moved to https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

Comment: How to install ?