# Convert scanned PDF to searcheable PDF (in R)

Tags: r, pdf, tesseract, pdftools, ropensci

I'm trying to convert a series of scanned PDF into searchable PDF using the `tesseract` and `pdftools` packages. I've accomplished two steps. Now I need to write back to a searchable pdf.

1. Read scanned PDF
2. Run OCR
3. Write back to a searcheable PDF

```
eg <- download.file("https://www.fujitsu.com/global/Images/sv600_c_automatic.pdf", "example.pdf", mode = "wb")

results <- tesseract::ocr_data("example.pdf", engine = "eng")
```

```
R> results
# A tibble: 406 x 3
   word        confidence bbox             
   <chr>            <dbl> <chr>            
 1 PFU               96.9 228,181,404,249  
 2 Business          96.2 459,180,847,249  
 3 report            96.2 895,182,1145,259 
 4 |                 52.5 3980,215,3984,222
 5 No.068            91.0 4439,163,4754,237
 6 New               96.0 493,503,1005,687 
 7 customer's        94.6 1069,484,2231,683
 8 development       96.5 2304,483,3714,732
 9 di                90.4 767,763,1009,959 
10 ing               96.3 1754,773,1786,807
# ... with 396 more rows
```

Alternatively, is there another package or command-line tool I can invoke in R for Windows?

Comment: It seems like the command line version of tesseract can do this on the image `C:\Users\tspeidel\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe example_1.png out -l eng PDF`. Still not sure how I can use it.

Comment: you could call that code with the R `system` function.

Comment: similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68976835/store-tesseract-output-in-pdf-using-r?) a couple of days ago and I dont think pdf output has been implemented. I think the system call is probably easiest but you can use rmarkdown::render e.g. `results <- tesseract::ocr("example.pdf", engine = "eng") ; cat(results, file=temp<-tempfile()) ; rmarkdown::render(temp, "pdf_document", "~/test.pdf")`

Comment: See related github issue: https://github.com/ropensci/tesseract/issues/51

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need and wrote a simple function in R to call the command line for OCRmyPDF.

I'm using Ubuntu, so first install OCRmyPDF in Ubuntu via:

```
sudo apt install ocrmypdf
```

Here's the info for [installing it on other operating systems](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

**Then load up the R function in R by running:**

```
    ocr_my_pdf <- function(path_read, ..., path_save = NULL){
      
      path_read <- here::here(path_read)
      if(is.null(path_save)){ 
        path_save <- stringr::str_replace(path_read, '(?i)\\.pdf$','_ocr.pdf') 
      } else {
        path_save <- here::here(path_save)
      }
      
      sys_args <- c(
        glue::glue("'{unlist(list(...))}'"), 
        glue::glue("'{path_read}'"), 
        glue::glue("'{path_save}'"))
      system2('ocrmypdf', args = sys_args) 
      
    }
```

**Then call the function on a test PDF with:**

```
    ocr_my_pdf('/home/test.pdf')
```

Or, with whatever additional arguments you want to pass:

```
    ocr_my_pdf('test.pdf', '--deskew', '--clean', '--rotate-pages')
```

Here's the info for [available arguments](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach based on the RDCOMClient R package. Basically, we convert the PDF to Word. In the process, Word uses an embedded OCR. Afterwards, with the Word software, we convert the Word document to a searchable PDF.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

download.file("https://www.fujitsu.com/global/Images/sv600_c_automatic.pdf", "example.pdf", mode = "wb")

path_PDF <- "C:/example.pdf"
path_Word <- "C:/example.docx"

################################################################
#### Step 1 : Convert PDF to word document with OCR of Word ####
################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_Word)
doc_Selection <- wordApp$Selection()

##########################################################
#### Step 3 : Convert word document to searchable pdf ####
##########################################################
path_PDF_Searchable <- "C:/example_searchable.pdf"
wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs(path_PDF_Searchable, FileFormat = 17) # FileFormat = 17 saves as .PDF
doc$Close()
wordApp$Quit() # quit wordApp
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the software ECopy installed on your computer (not a free software), you can use the following function to convert scanned pdfs to searchable pdfs:

```
ecopy_Scanned_PDF_To_Numeric_PDF <- function(directory_Scanned_PDF, directory_Numeric_PDF)
{
  path_To_BatchConverter <- "C:/Program Files (x86)/Nuance/eCopy PDF Pro Office 6/BatchConverter.com"
  args <- paste0("-I", directory_Scanned_PDF, "\\*.pdf -O", directory_Numeric_PDF, " -Tpdfs -Lfre -W -V1.5 -J -Ao")
  system2(path_To_BatchConverter, args = args)
}
```

I use this function at my job and it works very well